# CS50 Games Track: Mario

Tags: lua, cs50

I've been stuck on this for about two weeks now and I am still motivated to complete this because I'm so near the end of the course!

I've been able to generate the pyramids and flags correctly, and ensuring that no mushrooms or bushes generate past my pyramid to the end of the level.

However the part that I can't seem to get my head around is here:

```
-- 10% chance to not generate anything, creating a gap
elseif math.random(10) ~= 1 then
            -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end

            -- chance to create a block for Mario to hit
            if math.random(15) == 1 and x < self.mapWidth - 10 then
                self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 4, JUMP_BLOCK)
            end

            -- next vertical scan line
            x = x + 1
        else
            -- increment X so we skip two scanlines, creating a 2-tile gap
            x = x + 2
        end
```

I have placed the code generating the pyramid and flag after all the other entites. However it seems like if the condition in the above code block is fulfilled ( math.random(10) == 1 ), the last part of my map will just be one big gap and the pyramid and flag will all be gone.

As the logic of math.random is flipped in the case of creating gaps, how do I prevent gaps from generating past an arbitrary point (e.g. x < self.mapWidth - 10)? I've tried by simply adding ' and x < self.mapWidth - 10 ' to the elseif condition but I do not think that is the right thing to do.

The rest of the code concerning the generation is below, nothing else has changed:

```
-- begin generating the terrain using vertical scan lines
    local x = 1
    while x < self.mapWidth do

        -- 2% chance to generate a cloud
        -- make sure we're 2 tiles from edge at least
        if x < self.mapWidth - 2 then
            if math.random(20) == 1 then

                -- choose a random vertical spot above where blocks/pipes generate
                local cloudStart = math.random(self.mapHeight / 2 - 6)

                self:setTile(x, cloudStart, CLOUD_LEFT)
                self:setTile(x + 1, cloudStart, CLOUD_RIGHT)
            end
        end

        -- 5% chance to generate a mushroom
        if math.random(20) == 1 and x < self.mapWidth - 10 then
            -- left side of pipe
            self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 2, MUSHROOM_TOP)
            self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 1, MUSHROOM_BOTTOM)

            -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end

            -- next vertical scan line
            x = x + 1

        -- 10% chance to generate bush, being sure to generate away from edge
        elseif math.random(10) == 1 and x < self.mapWidth - 10 then
            local bushLevel = self.mapHeight / 2 - 1

            -- place bush component and then column of bricks
            self:setTile(x, bushLevel, BUSH_LEFT)
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end
            x = x + 1

            self:setTile(x, bushLevel, BUSH_RIGHT)
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end
            x = x + 1

        -- 10% chance to not generate anything, creating a gap
        elseif math.random(10) ~= 1 then
            -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end

            -- chance to create a block for Mario to hit
            if math.random(15) == 1 and x < self.mapWidth - 10 then
                self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 4, JUMP_BLOCK)
            end

            -- next vertical scan line
            x = x + 1
        else
            -- increment X so we skip two scanlines, creating a 2-tile gap
            x = x + 2
        end

         -- generate pyramid starting at least 7 blocks away from right edge
        if x == self.mapWidth - 7 then
            for j = 1, 4, 1 do
                self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - j, TILE_BRICK)

                -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
                for y = self.mapHeight / 2 - (j - 1), self.mapHeight / 2 - 1 do
                    self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
                end
                x = x + 1

                -- ensure nothing is generated between pyramid and flag
                for y = 0, self.mapHeight / 2 - 1 do
                    self:setTile(x, y, TILE_EMPTY)
                end

                for x = self.mapWidth - 7, self.mapWidth do
                    for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                        self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: your code says  `math.random ~= 1` , your post says `math.random == 1`  `if math.random(10) ~= 1` does not result in 10% but 90%

Comment: thanks for the heads up, forgot to undo an old edit. despite this change, when the probability is in the favour of the code generating a gap ( `x = x + 2` ), the entire last part of the map is totally gone. How does this occur?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that I had wrested with for a while as well. The best way I've come to understand the problem is this...

The end of level procedural generation is ONLY triggered when the x variable reaches `self.mapWidth - 7` since the procedural generation of the level isn't in the form of a `for x = 1, self.mapWidth do` it's not implicit that `x == self.mapWidth - 7` will be reached in every loading of the map.

To solve this I put the end of the level coding sequence in the Map.lua file after the part that said

```
 -- first, fill map with empty tiles
    for y = 1, self.mapHeight do
        for x = 1, self.mapWidth do
            
            -- support for multiple sheets per tile; storing tiles as tables 
            self:setTile(x, y, TILE_EMPTY)
        end
    end
```

started coding in the formula to create the pyramid and the flag pole an appropriate distance from the end of the self.mapWidth

```
-- create the end of level terrain 
    
    -- make local variables for ease of editing
    local PFront = self.mapWidth - 22
    local PEnd = self.mapWidth - 15
    local PTop = self.mapHeight / 2 - 1
    local PBottom = self.mapHeight / 2 - 1

    for x = PFront, PEnd, 1 do
        for y = PBottom, PTop, -1 do
            self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
        end
        PTop = PTop - 1
    end
      
    -- Generates a uniform ground for the final section
    for x = self.mapWidth - 22, self.mapWidth do
        for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
            self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
        end
    end

    -- Flag pole with declared top and bottom with iterated shaft
    for y = self.mapHeight / 2 - 7, self.mapHeight / 2 - 2 do
        self:setTile(self.mapWidth - 6, y, MIDDLE_POLE)
    end
    self:setTile(self.mapWidth - 6, self.mapHeight / 2 - 8, TOP_POLE)
    self:setTile(self.mapWidth - 6, self.mapHeight / 2 - 1, BOTTOM_POLE)
```

and then after all of that continue to the while... do loop formula from the class code.

```
 -- begin generating the terrain using vertical scan lines
    x = 1
    while x <= self.mapWidth - 23 do
    
    ...the rest of the Map.lua file
```

NOTE: in the `function Map:init()` function I changed the `self.mapWidth` to a greater value to allow more room to play the end of level area so it didn't encroach to far into the procedurally generated area.